# Why doesn't the Sovereign directly ask Darrow about his allegiance?

Tags: red-rising

In the Golden Son, during the game of questions, the Sovereign comes very close to discovering Darrow's identity and his mission. She suspects that he works for Ares, yet never asks the obvious question: "Do you work for Ares?" Assuming that Darrow does not want to be dying slowly in her cells it will let her learn all what he knows about the rebellion and may be even his true origin. And we are left to believe that Virginia's interruption made the Sovereign forget about this ultimate question, which she approached the whole game?

Why didn't she ask this question? Are my assumptions incorrect? Am I missing something?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking, please edit to clarify and elaborate?

Answer (score 4):

The Sovereign does not -at this point, at least- think Darrow works for the Sons of Ares. What she believes is that the Sons of Ares are working under the direct influence of Arch Governor Augustus.

That's why she never asks point blank if Darrow is with the Sons. The whole innuendo is to try and make Darrow betray Augustus.